# Axis2 webservice - Input parameter name not generated as specified in the Interface method

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-axis

I'm a newbie to axis2 programming. I'm trying to generate a webservice using bottom-up approach from a Java interface. I have a method with one parameter in the interface which has to be exposed as a webservice.

There was no issue in generating & running the service. Below is the interface that was used to generate webservice. In WSDL, the parameter name generated for the webservice is args0.

```
interface sample {
String populateForm(String inputDetail) ;
}
```

The part of wsdl generated

```
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
targetNamespace="http://web.example.net">
<xs:element name="populateForm">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="args0" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="populateFormResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

I require the parameter name to be **inputDetail** instead of **args0**. Can anyone help to resolve my problem?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in axis2 where when interface is used as base class to create web service, parameters are generated as args0, arg1, etc. I used a simple class instead of interface and obtained the object for implementation method through spring application context. This method worked.